# How can I get only the visible part of line-data in Matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib

Is it possible to get the visible part only of data after using the *zoom-to-rectangle* feature of a Matplotlib plot ?

For clarity, if I first do

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(nrows=1, ncols=1)
ax.plot(x,y)
```

Then secondly, I manually use the *zoom* tool on the figure such that only parts of the data is visible.

Thirdly, I run the snippet

```
x_zoom = ax.get_lines()[0].get_xdata()
y_zoom = ax.get_lines()[0].get_ydata()
```

but this will yield an `x_zoom` equal to `x` and a `y_zoom` equal to `y`, which is not what I want.

Comment: Are you looking for ```ax.get_xlim()``` and ```ax.get_ylim()```?

Comment: No. I want the data that is visible within the interval of the zoom'd plot. I think the way to go is `elements = (x >= ax.get_xlim()[0]) & (x <= ax.get_xlim()[1])` and then `xdata, ydata = x[elements], y[elements]`